# Set the role of a .NET Windows service at install time...from app.config settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have a service that when installed puts the Myapp.exe.config file (generated based of the app.config file) into the install directory.  During the install process I need details from this file to configure the install.  Particularly I need to tweak the Account/Username/Password fields of my service's ServiceProcessInstaller instance so when it runs it runs as a particular user.

However, during the install process the installer hasn't set my registry settings yet nor copied my Myapp.exe.config to the install directory...so I have no way of pulling these values, which means my service cannot install as the correct user.  The only way I can do it now is to hardcode the user/pass values into the ProjectInstaller class, but I can't bring myself to do it this way.  It's just wrong.

Is there a Windows install best practice regarding how to install a service as a particular user and how to access those credentials during the install process.

Currently I'm trying something like:

```
namespace MyService
{
   [RunInstaller(true)]
   public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
   {
      public ProjectInstaller()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         //Set the user credentials.
         //NOTE: Eventually this needs to be updated to pull these values out of a
         //      conf file.  The problem now is that the location of the conf file
         //      is tied to a registry entry for the location of the service which
         //      may or may not exist when this block is executed.
         /* This is the only way I can get it to work, but this is
          * too horrible to ever actually do it this way:
         serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
         serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = "DOMAIN\\user";
         serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = "password";
          */

         // Try to pull the service's registry values to know where it installed:
         RegistryKey keyService = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\MyService");
         string path = ((string)keyService.GetValue("ImagePath"));
         path = path.Substring(1, path.LastIndexOf('\\'));

         string user = someValueFromFileIOontheAbovePath1,
                pass = someValueFromFileIOontheAbovePath2;

         serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
         serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = user;
         serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = pass;
         //Doesn't work because install isn't complete and there aren't reg settings
         // yet, and even if I had the path the .config file is not written yet so
         // there's no file to parse.
      }
   }
}
```

Some .config file that holds these parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="User" value="DOMAIN\bob"/>
      <add key="Password" value="secret"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

How can I pull these user/pass values *during* install without resorting to hardcoding them into the binary?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the MSI Setup built into visual studio?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thanks for the comment.  Anyway I added a simple Deployment project (vdproj) to my solution, which does emit a setup and .msi file when built.  Although really all that deployment project does is access the ServiceProcessInstaller object internal to my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want with the MSI is to use a Custom Action on the Commit to run your custom object installer.  Commit Actions are run after the files have been copied, so the files will exist in the installation directory your user has chosen.

Comment: Thanks Erik.  On commit I'm aware I can run some other executable, but is there some way I can access the ServiceProcessInstaller in my service code?  I'm not aware of any other place where I can actually set the user/pass than _inside_ this object's code in the service itself.

Comment: I almost always write my windows services as self installers with parameters, then manually run the EXE on commit.  This is my personal preference because if the installer itself gets corrupt or something happens to the exe/msi, it can be very painful to manually remove a service.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options with varying levels of security.

1) If you specify ServiceAccount.User but do not give a username and password, Microsoft's class will pop up a window for the credentials to be entered.  This is pretty secure because the credentials are never stored anywhere but the popup doesn't really make it clear to the person running the installer what they are entering.  Plus the popup doesn't really flow very nicely with the other install screens.

2) You can have the MSI pass the username and password as parameters to your installer class.  The values are left in plain text in the InstallLog file though so you'll want to delete that for sure.

3) Have the MSI encrypt the name/password in the registry using DPAPI (System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData class) and then unencrypt them and use them in your service installer class.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know that was the behavior.  If I can't get it to work any other way this is an option.